# inconvertible types error in mongodb java?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

```java
 final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
 DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("NAME", -1));
 AggregateIterable <Document> aggregate = collection.aggregate((List<? extends Bson>) asList(group,sort));
```

That code is throwing this error:

> could not parse error message:   required: List
>   found:    List

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the java driver 2.x api with 3.x driver api.

`MongoCollection`, `MongoDatabase`, `Document`/`Bson` are 3.x classes whereas `DBCollection`, `DB` and `BasicDBObject`/`DBObject` are 2.x classes.

Looks like you are using 3.x driver, so you've to do something like below.

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("db");
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("collection");

 BsonField id = Accumulators.first("ID", "$ID");
 BsonField name = Accumulators.first("NAME", "NAME");
 BsonField amount = Accumulators.sum("amount", "$amount");

 Bson group = Aggregates.group("$NAME", id, name, amount);
 Bson sort = Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("NAME"));

 List<Document> results = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(group, sort)).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

More information here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/

Comment: Can you look at the question in the and help me out there [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/42949980/7720299) @Veeram