# indexoutofboundsexception in Mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
for(int i=0; i<= field.length; i++){
    String[] field = allFields.split(",");
    String field1 = "$"+field[i];
    BsonField includeFields = Accumulators.first(field[i], field1);
    includeList.add(includeFields);
}
    group = Aggregates.group(groupByField,includeList);
```

where the allFields will have the columns i want to select("ID,NAME").

why is it giving me  indexoutofboundsexception ?

Comment: ensure i value in field[i]  didnot exceed the length of field

Comment: when i print includeFields `name='ID', value=Expression{name='$first', expression=$ID} `. Is the exception because of this @radhakrishnan

Comment: Where is `i` defined ?

Comment: i resolved it by removing = in the loop   `for(int i=0; i<= field.length; i++){`  @Veeram

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference for future visitors
Suppose we have an array called `foo` which contains 10 items.
What happens if we try to iterate using the following code?:

```
for(int i = 0;i<=foo.length;i++){
   //some code that uses foo[i] here
}
```

The answer is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
The reason is simple.As said before `foo` contains 10 elements
which means you can access them using `foo[0] to foo[9]`
Since array indexing starts from 0 `foo[9]` contains the last element in your array(the 10th element)`

What happens though in the `for` loop?

As you iterate you always check `i<=foo.length` to continue.
The problem is that when the value of `i` is 9 the expression `i<=foo.length(which means i<=10)` evaluates to `true`.That means that the `for` loop will run for one last time.When this happens in your loop you will try to access `foo[10]` which not exists and hence the  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

So remember that when you want to iterate over an array you *always* use  `i<foo.length`

So as you too figured it out the solution to your problem is this:

```
for(int i=0; i< field.length; i++){
    String[] field = allFields.split(",");
    String field1 = "$"+field[i];
    BsonField includeFields = Accumulators.first(field[i], field1);
    includeList.add(includeFields);
}
```